# Как лучше сделать выделение блока div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

Нужно сделать чтобы при клике оставался фон `#EEEEEE`, как сейчас при наведении `hover`. Копать в этом направлении `.removeClass .addClass` ? Или это можно сделать способом проще?

```css
.fdfd:hover{
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.check{
 position: relative;
}

.check label{
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 background: #EEEEEE;
 top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

.check label:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 background: transparent;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 
 border-top: none;
 border-right: none;

 
}

.check label:hover::after {
 background-color: #DEDEDE;
}

.check input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
 background-color: #2ECC71;
}

.tab1_checkbox{
 float: left;
 width: 2%;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.tab1{
 float: left;
 width: 5%;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.tab2{
 float: left;
 width: 53%;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.tab3{
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.tab4{
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fdfd">
<label for="check4">
 <div class="tab1_checkbox">
 <div class="check">
  <input id="check4" class="checkbox" name="name[]" value="4" type="checkbox">
  <label for="check4"></label>
 </div>
 </div>  
  <div class="tab1">4</div>
  <div class="tab2">Гироскутер Flamingo</div>
  <div class="tab3">177</div>
  <div class="tab4">8599 грн.</div>
</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По хорошему эта верстка никуда не годится и надо ее полностью переделывать. Половина CSS ни на что не влияет, все `float:left` успешно решаются через один `display:inline-block`.

Но отвечая на вопрос, можно так:

```js
document.querySelector(".fdfd").addEventListener("click",function(e){
    if(e.target.type != "checkbox"){
        if(this.style.backgroundColor != ""){
            this.style.backgroundColor = "";
            this.style.width = "";
            this.style.overflow = "";
        }else{
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#EEEEEE";
            this.style.width = "100%";
            this.style.overflow = "hidden";
        }
        
    }
    
})
```

```css
.fdfd:hover, .active{
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.check{
 position: relative;
}

.check label{
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 background: #EEEEEE;
 top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

.check label:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 background: transparent;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 
 border-top: none;
 border-right: none;

 
}

.check label:hover::after {
 background-color: #DEDEDE;
}

.check input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
 background-color: #2ECC71;
}

.tab1_checkbox{
 float: left;
 width: 2%;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.tab1{
 float: left;
 width: 5%;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.tab2{
 float: left;
 width: 53%;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.tab3{
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.tab4{
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fdfd">
<label for="check4">
 <div class="tab1_checkbox">
 <div class="check">
  <input id="check4" class="checkbox" name="name[]" value="4" type="checkbox">
  <label for="check4"></label>
 </div>
 </div>  
  <div class="tab1">4</div>
  <div class="tab2">Гироскутер Flamingo</div>
  <div class="tab3">177</div>
  <div class="tab4">8599 грн.</div>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но отмена чекбокса не работает, он остается выделенным

Comment: @emtecif, обновил, но лучше сделать нормальную верстку и воспользоваться сменой классов `.removeClass .addClass`. Поищите и посмотрите аналогичные примеры.

Comment: спасибо, тут работает, но у меня на сайте все равно чего то не работает, буду разбираться...

Answer (score 1):

Нужно изменить стиль:

```
.fdfd:hover{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

на

```
.fdfd:hover,.fdfd.active{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

и добавить JS:

```
function addEvent(elem, type, handler){
  if (elem.addEventListener){
    elem.addEventListener(type, handler, false)
  } else {
    elem.attachEvent("on"+type, handler)
  }
} 
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".fdfd");
for(var i=0; i<elements.length;i++){
    addEvent(elements[i],"click",function(){this.classList.toggle('active');});
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b90enm38/2/ - здесь работает, но при отмене не возвращает прошлый стиль

Comment: @emtecif Изменил функцию добавления класса на переключение

Comment: вообще перестало работать https://jsfiddle.net/b90enm38/3/ ))

Comment: у меня не работает, ни в Firefox, ни в Opera, ни в Chrome)